# Set Application level proxy in .Net 5.0 project

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-5

I have to set a proxy for the .net 5.0 application. I referred https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.defaultproxy?view=net-5.0 which mentioned I can set HTTP_PROXY environment variable, which will be used for all the calls.
Another option is I use HttpClientHandler to set the proxy for every client.

Is there a way I can set the proxy at the application level so that other applications don't get affected(this might happen in the case of setting the env variable)? And I don't want to set proxy at individual client level(HttpClient, SecretClient, etc).

Comment: The first line of the Remarks of the linked documentation states "This static property determines the default proxy that all `HttpClient` instances use if no proxy is set explicitly in the `HttpClientHandler` passed through its constructor." So, when your application is initialized, set that static property to the proxy. It will then be set at the application level.

Answer (score 1):

Environment variables are not necessarily system-wide.

To state from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Syntax), "In all Unix and Unix-like systems, as well as on Windows, each process has its own separate set of environment variables. By default, when a process is created, it inherits a duplicate run-time environment of its parent process".

If you don't set variables system-wide, the environment variables will stay in that process and its children.

Launching applications in the same process or child process would lead to the problem you described, but when you use different processes you should be fine.

This can also be used with Dockerfiles if you are still worried about interference.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for all clients(httpclient and SecretClient), at the process level.

```
 HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
 handler.Proxy = new WebProxy("Proxyaddress:proxyPort", true);
 Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("HTTP_PROXY", "Proxyaddress:proxyPort");
 Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("HTTPS_PROXY", "Proxyaddress:proxyPort");
```